# Apache2/glassfish|tomcat: Redirecting some (but not all) requests on 80 to glassfish on port 8080, where is the admin screen?

Tags: tomcat, configuration, httpd, mod-proxy, glassfish

Using that answer: [How to redirect traffic on port 80 to Tomcat port 8080 whilst still allowing the server to send/receive on port 80](https://serverfault.com/questions/262346)

I've configured my apache2 server to redirect some requests to glassfish on 8080:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
(...)
ProxyPass /tomcat/ http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /tomcat/ http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPass /tomcat-admin/ http://localhost:4848/
ProxyPassReverse /tomcat-admin/ http://localhost:4848/
</VirtualHost>
```

On http://my.server.org/tomcat/ , I can clearly see:

```
 GlassFish Server 3.1.2
Your server is now running
```

but http://my.server.org/tomcat-admin/ returns a **blank** screen , but I can see the HTML source of the admin page, so I suppose that some resources cannot be loaded. How should I fix this ?

Another question: if my java web application use **httpS**, should I just add:

```
ProxyPass /tomcat-secure/ http://localhost:8443/
ProxyPassReverse /tomcat-secure/ http://localhost:8443/
</VirtualHost>
```

?

Comment: What do your apache logs say?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know anything about that apache-proxy stuff. However, I had a similar problem and my workaround may help you to solve your issue.

I fully integrated tomcat into apache using `mod-jk`. Assuming you're using a Debian-based distro just install `libapache2-mod-jk` and configure the module in `/etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties`. You may need something like this:

```
worker.ajp13_worker.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker.type=ajp13
```

These parameters define the connection between apache and tomcat. I told tomcat to only listen to `127.0.0.1`. But it should be fine to configure the module to speak to another IP and/or a different port if you need a standalone tomcat installation available without apache.

Next step: Open `/etc/apache2/mods-available/jk.conf` and make sure that apache reads these properties:

```
JkWorkersFile /etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties
```

If that is done, the communication between apache and tomcat should work. Now you can create some hosts forwarding their requests to tomcat:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    [...]
    ServerName your.host.tld
    [...]
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /YourContext/$1 [L,PT]
    JkMount /* ajp13_worker
    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

This virtual host will forward each request to the context `YourContext` at tomcat. `ajp13_worker` is the worker-definition as previously configured in `/etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties` (of course you can configure multiple workers for different IPs/ports) and the `RewriteRule` rewrites the query to prefix it with `YourContext`. So you also need the rewrite module, if it's not already enabled. Enable the modules and this host:

```
a2enmod jk
a2enmod rewrite
a2ensite 007-what-ever-host
service apache2 restart
service tomcat7 restart
```

and go for `http://your.host.tld/abc?some=query`. You'll hopefully end up with the same result as if you call `http://your.host.tld:8080/YourContext/abc?some=query`.

Hope that helps ;-)